# tracking Token holder throughout a value chain of product

Tags: solidity, blockchain, tokens, besu

my project is Value chain of product , so i need to track every single process in the chain of that product , from Farmer => Transportation => Manufacturer => Distribution => Retailer
first step the Farmer will mint a Token based on the product and the quantity where
1Kg of fruit = 1 Token of raw product
then the farmer will give that Token to the transportation which will add to that Token a new log of the holder but not the owner because the transport doesn't own the Token just hold it for specific period of time , and the transportation will give that Token to the manufacturer and so on.
i had idea to add inside the generated Token a list[] , at every transaction we append the current holder of the Token
example
TokenList[farmer]    ( generated by farmer )
TokenList[farmer,transportation] ( the farmer transfer the Token to the transport )
TokenLIst[farmer,transportation,manufacturer] ( the transport transfer the Token to manufactuer )
TokenList[farmer,transportation,manufacturer,...,...,...,consumer] ( the Token is held by the consumer )

if you have any other suggestion or implementation thanks in advance , the solution is for private  besu network the gas fee doesn't really matter